# Is there a way to provide a Select All / Check All checkbox for a field that displays multiple checkboxes in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, nodes

Seems like there is no core config to setup a "Check All" checkbox unless I missed where it is. I'm creating a content type and have a taxonomy reference field and I have alot of terms, which means alot of boxes I have to check. Anyway to provide a checkbox to select everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an updated version of @duckx code, it has the following improvements :
- only select the checkboxes of the label that has been clicked
- allows to toggle checkboxes

```
Drupal.behaviors.selectAll = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $('body.page-node .form-type-checkboxes > label').click(function() {
        $(this).nextAll('.form-checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: which file does Drupal.behaviros.selectAll go?

Comment: I generally put this in a script.js inside my theme, don't forget to wrap it inside `(function ($) { ... })(jQuery);` as usual.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a form alter. [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and attach your js to the form.

```
$form['#attached']['js'] = array(
  drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURMODULE') . '/YOURMODULE.js',
);
```

Then add the code as in [here](https://snipt.net/asdflars/drupal-check-all-checkbox/)

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick snippet for anyone looking for a quick check all functionality. It will basically make your field LABEL a check all button. **No need to add any extra HTML elements or modules.** This just works.

You can pretty much copy this into your js file and it will just work as i restrained it to working only on content Edit pages.

Obviously this isn't a long term solution, but mainly as a quick band aid patch.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
  $('body.page-node .form-type-checkboxes > label').click(function() {
      $checkBoxes.attr('checked', true);
  });                                                                                                                                                                                            
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This contrib module appears to do the trick: https://www.drupal.org/project/checkall

Answer (score 0):

There is no core config option for something like this, it would have to be JavaScript/jQuery (http://jsfiddle.net/PtMrM/).

```
<a href="#" class="check-all">Check All</a>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="ny"> New York</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="bos"> Boston</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="sfo"> San Francisco</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" name="dc"> Wasington DC</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($) {
    var $checkBoxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $('.check-all').click(function() {
      $checkBoxes.attr('checked', true);
    });
  }(jQuery))
</script>
```

Please note, that is very quick js, and won't be very user friendly (e.g., they click on it, there is no way to uncheck)