# Drupal 7 check all solution for 2017, is it possible?

Tags: theming

I looked online, tried the checkall module, nothing works, found info from posts in 2013...

[Is there a way to provide a Select All / Check All checkbox for a field that displays multiple checkboxes in Drupal 7?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78296/is-there-a-way-to-provide-a-select-all-check-all-checkbox-for-a-field-that-dis)

Nothing conclusive, just half baked hacks that might or might not work.

Any solution that works for 2017?

Even the Google chrome check all extensions are buggy...only thing that works in older versions of firefox for this...

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: try `$(this).nextAll('input:checkbox').trigger('click');`

Comment: Thank you nosweat, but in what file and what directory please? I use D7 with boostrap subtheme, backend is Seven

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a custom module for this

**my_module.module**

```
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
     if($form['#node']->type == "my_content_type") {
        $form['#attached']['js'][] = array(
          'data' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/js/example.js',
          'type' => 'file', 
        );
     }
}
```

- Change all `my_module` to the actual name of your module
- Change `my_content_type` to the actual name of your content type.

**my_module/js/example.js**  ([using code from the link you gave](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/78296/is-there-a-way-to-provide-a-select-all-check-all-checkbox-for-a-field-that-dis))

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.selectAll = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        $('body.page-node .form-type-checkboxes > label').click(function() {
            $(this).nextAll('.form-checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');
        });
      }
    };
}(jQuery));
```

If it doesn't work, try changing the line

`$(this).nextAll('.form-checkboxes').find('input[type="checkbox"]').trigger('click');`

to

```
$(this).nextAll('input:checkbox').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Actually, I don't need this for a single content type, I need this functioanlity on ALL checkboxes on ALL back end items...is it possible?

Comment: @BrunoVincent then remove the conditional statement `if($form['#node']->type == "my_content_type") { }` part